# How to reorganize event listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript

I often find myself writing code as follows...

```
var startX, startY, dragging = false, element = document.getElementById("whatever");

var start = function(e){
  dragging = true;
  startX = e.pageX;
  startY = e.pageY;
  element.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

var move = function(e){
  if (!dragging) return;
  var deltaX = startX - e.pageX;
  var deltaY = startY - e.pageY;
  //apply to element
}

var end = function(e){
  dragging = false;
  element.style.opacity = 1;
}

element.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", end, false);
```

Now, my problem is really basic, it feels to me that the functions should be auxiliary and belong to the bottom part of my program, but I don't know how to attach the functions to the event listeners without declaring them first. How do I restructure my code so that it is more evident what I'm going to do with these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *hoisting*. Declare the functions wherever you want, in this case, later, but declare them this way:

```
function start(e){

}
```

When declared this way, they are hoisted ([read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610883/401137)), and can be used before the declaration.

Your code, restructured, would look like this:

```
var startX, startY, dragging = false, element = document.getElementById("whatever");



element.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", end, false);

function start(e){
  dragging = true;
  startX = e.pageX;
  startY = e.pageY;
  element.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

function move(e){
  if (!dragging) return;
  var deltaX = startX - e.pageX;
  var deltaY = startY - e.pageY;
  //apply to element
}

function end(e){
  dragging = false;
  element.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: I've been using javascript for so long and I had no idea about hoisting, thanks so much!

Comment: @Duopixel Sure. Not many people do.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply declare the functions inline, like:

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e){
  dragging = true;
  startX = e.pageX;
  startY = e.pageY;
  element.style.opacity = 0.5;
}, false);
```

And likewise for the other 2 functions.

But that can get messy in a hurry. Especially because `startX`, `startY` and `dragging` would still be outside.

So instead you could put the handler in an object literal, just to keep them separated:

```
var dragEvents, element = document.getElementById("whatever"),

dragEvents = (function () {
  var dragging = false, startX, startY;
  return {
    start: function (e){
      dragging = true;
      startX = e.pageX;
      startY = e.pageY;
      element.style.opacity = 0.5;
    },

    move: function (e){
      if (!dragging) return;
      var deltaX = startX - e.pageX;
      var deltaY = startY - e.pageY;
      //apply to element
    },

    end: function(e){
      dragging = false;
      element.style.opacity = 1;
    }
  };
}());

element.addEventListener("mousedown", dragEvents.start, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragEvents.move, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEvents.end, false);
```

I've wrapped it in an immediately invoked function so the dragging-related vars can be kept in there too.

However, might as well go the extra step and put everything in a function, instead of relying on `element` being a closure:

```
function makeDraggable(elementId) {
  var startX,
      startY,
      dragging = false,
      element = document.getElementById(elementId);

  function start(e){
    dragging = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY;
    element.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }

  function move(e){
    if (!dragging) return;
    var deltaX = startX - e.pageX;
    var deltaY = startY - e.pageY;
    //apply to element
  }

  function end(e){
    dragging = false;
    element.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  element.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", end, false);
}
```

The last suggestion I'd make would be to skip the `dragging` variable in favor of simply adding the `move` and `end` handlers on mouse down, and removing them on mouse up, like so:

```
function makeDraggable(elementId) {
  var startX,
      startY,
      element = document.getElementById(elementId);

  function move(e){
    var deltaX = startX - e.pageX;
    var deltaY = startY - e.pageY;
    //apply to element
  }

  function end(e){
    element.style.opacity = 1;
    element.removeEventListener("mousedown", move, false);
    element.removeEventListener("mousedown", end, false);
  }

  element.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e){
    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY;
    element.style.opacity = 0.5;
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", end, false);
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: Why is `dragging` a bad pattern? I've read that keeping state is bad in programming, but I'm not sure if it's related to this.

Comment: @Duopixel Personally, I just find it more straightforward to only have the event handlers there, when they're needed, instead of having them fire for _every_ mousemove and mouseup. No need to explicitly keep state